# Invalid Procedure call or argument when changing path

Tags: vbscript

I tried to combine a couple different scripts, which works fine until I change the path of `strPath`. The moment I change it to anything else I get an error message

> Invalid Procedure call or argument.

The script is meant to find the latest file in any directory (including subfolders), and copy and paste the file into a folder

```
Dim strPath, oFSO, oFile, oFolder, dteDate, strName, N 

strPath = "C:\Users\parjo16\Documents\Archived"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
  If oFile.DateLastModified > dteDate Then
    dteDate = oFile.DateLastModified
    strName = oFile.Name
  End If
  N = N + 1
Next 'oFile

Call FindTheSubFolderFiles(oFolder, N, dteDate, strNme)

Const strfolder = "C:\SalaryData\"
Const Overwrite = True
Dim oFSOd

Set oFSOd = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not oFSOd.FolderExists(strfolder) Then
  oFSOd.CreateFolder strfolder
End If

oFSOd.CopyFile strNme, strfolder & "salaries.xlsx", Overwrite

Set oFSOd = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
Set oFolder = Nothing

Function FindTheSubFolderFiles(ByRef oParentFolder, ByRef lngR, ByRef dteDte, ByRef strNme)
  Dim oSubFolder
  Dim oFile
  For Each oSubFolder In oParentFolder.SubFolders
    For Each oFile In oSubFolder.Files
      If oFile.DateLastModified > dteDte Then
        dteDte = oFile.DateLastModified
        strNme = oFile.Path
      End If
      lngR = lngR + 1
    Next
    FindTheSubFolderFiles oSubFolder, lngR, dteDte, strNme
  Next 'oSubFolder
  Set oSubFolder = Nothing
  Set oFile = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What *exactly* are you changing the value of `strPath` to, and which statement *exactly* is throwing the error?

Comment: I'm just trying to change it to any other path, for example C:\Users\parjo16\Documents\CloseFiles. The error is happing on oFSOd.CopyFile strNme, strfolder & "salaries.xlsx", Overwrite. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Check the values of `strNme` and `strFolder & "salaries.xlsx"` before trying to copy the file.

Comment: Thanks looks like I've found the issue now

Comment: Now that you have a working code, I advise you to move your entire code to [codereview.se] to get it reviewed and "cleaned"

Comment: Now that you have edited the question to include the answer, you don't have a question anymore, and you might as well delete the question. (What you could have done instead was post an _answer_ to your own question.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the script was doing two checks, one for the main folder, one for the subfolder. If the result is the other, then it comes back blank.

This seems to be working now:

```
Function FindTheSubFolderFiles(ByRef oParentFolder, ByRef lngR, ByRef dteDte, ByRef strNme)
    Dim oSubFolder
    Dim oFile
    For Each oSubFolder In oParentFolder.SubFolders
        For Each oFile In oSubFolder.Files
            If oFile.DateLastModified > dteDte Then
                dteDte = oFile.DateLastModified
                strNme = oFile.path
            End If
            lngR = lngR + 1
        Next
        FindTheSubFolderFiles oSubFolder, lngR, dteDte, strNme
    Next 'oSubFolder
    Set oSubFolder = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
End Function

Dim strPath, oFSO, oFile, oFolder, dteDate, strName, N
strPath = "C:\Users\parjo16\Documents\Archived\"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If oFile.DateLastModified > dteDate Then
        dteDate = oFile.DateLastModified
        strName = oFile.Name
    End If
    N = N + 1
Next 'oFile

Call FindTheSubFolderFiles(oFolder, N, dteDate, strNme)

Const strfolder = "C:\SalaryData\"
Const Overwrite = True
Dim oFSOd

Set oFSOd = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not oFSOd.FolderExists(strfolder) Then
    oFSOd.CreateFolder strfolder
End If

On Error Resume Next

oFSOd.CopyFile strPath & strName, strfolder & "salaries.xlsx", Overwrite
oFSOd.CopyFile strNme, strfolder & "salaries.xlsx", Overwrite

Set oFSOd = Nothing

Set oFSO = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
Set oFolder = Nothing
```